# Why UFW port range / number for ports is limited to 15 ports?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, port, ufw

Why UFW port range / number of ports is limited to 15 ports?

`man ufw`:

> You cannot specify more than 15 ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ufw is just a wrapper over iptables. When you use several ports in single rule, the underneath of ufw the iptables match `multiport` is used. The 15 count is the port number limit of this `multiport` match ([see the source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_multiport.h#L13)).